# A (continuous) inverse to derive (commutator sub group) functor on the Category of Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory

> Is there a  functor $\mathcal{F}$ on the category of  groups which satisfy $$D \circ \mathcal{F}=\mathrm{Id}$$
>   where $D$ is the derive (commutator  subgroup) functor?

Is this (possible) functor continuous?

Recall that: A continuous  functor on the Category of groups is  a  functor which commute with direct limit (Up to isomorphism): That is  a  functor $\mathcal{F}$   such that $\mathcal{F}( \lim\limits_{\longrightarrow} G_{\alpha})\simeq  \lim\limits_{\longrightarrow} \mathcal{F}(G_{\alpha})$.

Comment: Aren't you saying that if $G$ and $G'$ have isomorphism commutators then they are isomorphic. This is patently false (e.g. abelian groups).

Comment: I think the best you can have is that the inclusion functor $Ab \to G$ from the category of abelian groups to the category of groups has as its left adjoint the abelianization functor. Moreover as Alex Youcis points out, what you want is not possible. The abelianization functor is "quite rough" since e.g. the abelianization of every knot group is $\mathbb{Z}$ and the abelianization of any Right angled artin group with defining graph having $n$ vertices is $\mathbb{Z^n}$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis  I do not see what is a relation between my question and your comment. Could you please more explain?

Comment: @M.U.  I bold the main part of my question and I move the first part to the last part. Can I ask you to more explain on your comment?

Comment: @AlexYoucis If the question was about $F\circ D={\rm Id}$, I'd see how that'd mean every group can be recovered from its derived subgroup, which is impossible. But I don't see that interpretation for $D\circ F={\rm Id}$. Instead, the first question seems to be which groups can be derived subgroups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not even possible on the level of objects, let alone morphisms; [not every group is a commutator subgroup](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Derived_subgroup#Group_properties).